# wget - file name extension for incomplete downloads (e.g. file.zip.incomplete or file.zip.part)

Tags: http, ftp, wget, mirroring

I want to mirror http and ftp directories with **wget** and I want to identify incomplete downloads of wget. Is there a way that incomplete downloads get an additional file extension like ".part" or ".incomplete"?

Sometimes I don't have a download log and I don't know the exact file size of a file. (The downloads are often not complete because of bad ftp/http server or bad internet connection)

For only one download of a file I could write a kind of wrapper:

1. `wget -c -O file.zip.part http://domain.tld/file.zip`
2. (if finished) `mv file.zip.part file.zip`

I am not sure how to do it for directories.

Kind regards

matt

Comment: your wrapper should do the trick, I'm not to sure what your problem is with directories. Can you clarify?

Comment: I don't have a complete list of the files (download links).

Comment: are you confusing wget and curl ?